# Is there method to validate the access token using google token endpoint in Authlib? #Authlib

Tags: python, fastapi, authlib

I am trying to evaluate authlib support for following use cases with google oauth2.

1. Fetch the authorization code
2. Fetch the token
3. Validate the token against google token endpoint
4. Refresh the token using refresh token

I could implement 1, 2 and 4. However could not find any method or mechanism to validate the obtained access token against the google token endpoint. Requirement is to validate the token for the expiry/active before proceeding with further operations in the server.

Is there method to validate the access token using google token endpoint in Authlib?

I tried using the introspection method which didn't work.

Comment: first `decode`, then call `validate` on the claim and with `claim_options` as necessary depending on what you want to validate?

Comment: I don't mean to just validate the signature of id_token which is JWT. I want to validate the token against the google token endpoint to check if it's valid and active. I understand that I can check the expiry time of the token persisted in local data-store, however it might skip the cases where token is revoked by external action.

I wanted to check if there is something in Authlib which can validate the token against the https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo endpoint of google.

Comment: In that case it seems you're looking for `introspect_token`, as that is the implemented method in authlib: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/api.html#authlib.integrations.httpx_client.AsyncOAuth2Client.introspect_token - however, I don't think Google implements RFC 7662 :(